# Delete[] on pointer to new[]d array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am confused why delete[] (and delete as well for that matter) fail when I try calling it on a pointer that's pointing to the memory I new'd.

```
// Start with output first
float* sigmas = new float[_M];
float* sigmasNext = new float[_M];
for (int i = 0; i < _M; i++) // Loop through and attempt to learn the outputs
{
    sigmas[i] = _output[i].Learn(inputValues, outputValues[i]); // Learn
}

// Then the hidden layers
float* weights;

// The first layer
for (int j = 0; j < _H[0]; j++)
{
    weights = new float[_M];
    for (int k = 0; k < _M; k++)
    {
        weights[k] = _output[k].GetWeights()[j];
    }
    sigmasNext[j] = _hidden[0][j].Learn(inputValues, sigmas, weights, _M);
    delete [] weights;
}
delete [] sigmas;

// The other hidden layers
for (int i = 1; i < _Hcount; i++)
{
    sigmas = sigmasNext;
    sigmasNext = new float[_H[i - 1]];
    for (int j = 0; j < _H[i]; j++)
    {
        weights = new float[_H[i - 1]];
        for (int k = 0; k < _H[i - 1]; k++)
        {
            weights[k] = _hidden[i - 1][k].GetWeights()[j];
        }
        sigmasNext[j] = _hidden[i][j].Learn(inputValues, sigmas, weights, _H[i - 1]);
        delete [] weights;
    }
    delete [] sigmas;
}
```

Learn():

```
float sigma;

// Get the output of this neuron
float net = Net(inputs);
float out = FireOnNet(net);
float derive = DerivedValue(net);

// Learning
// Sigma(hidden)[i] = sum(sigma[k] * w[k]; 1 -> K) * f'(net)
// deltaW[i] = alpha * sigma * net
if (_type == Output)
{
    throw 0; // Should probably throw a real exception here
}
else // if (_type == Hidden)
{
    sigma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sigmaCount; i++)
    {
        sigma += sigmas[i] * weights[i] * derive;
    }
    sigma *= derive;
}
_deltaWeights[0] += alpha * sigma * 1; // Adjust the BIAS weight //////
for (int i = 1; i < _numOfWeights; i++) // Adjust the other weights
{
    _deltaWeights[i] += alpha * sigma * inputs[i - 1];
}

return sigma;
```

I crash on the second delete[] sigmas; (at the end of the first code block) but if sigmas is pointing to the heap allocated by sigmasNext, why does it crash? What would be the correct way of deallocating sigmasNext while holding onto it for the next loop?

Comment: Can you make this an [mcve]?

Comment: @Sreekar No kidding. There is so little code there is no possible way for you to duplicate the OP's problem. Almost certainly a buffer overrun or rogue pointer in the missing code that smashes the allocation's control block or a second delete.

Comment: So you're saying that this kind of operation should work in theory? You can delete from a different variable as long as it points to the same memory, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allocting an array of _M floats

```
float* sigmasNext = new float[_M];
```

and writing elements 0.._H[0]

```
for (int j = 0; j < _H[0]; j++)
    sigmasNext[j] = ...
```

respectively writing elements 0.._H[i]

```
for (int j = 0; j < _H[i]; j++)
    sigmasNext[j] = ...
```

I'ld guess that you are writing more than _M elements into the array, thus corrupting memory management structures, thus causing `delete []` to crash.

This would not have happened, if you did not use raw pointers but STL containers like vector. vector would assert in debug mode and tell you if you access elements at an invalid index.

Comment: Yes! That's it! I see. I've been getting too used to languages yelling at me about going over bounds that I had not even thought of that. Thanks so much! I see now that C++ stores some extra info about arrays at the end, never knew that.